# Netlify Lambda functions: keep getting path must be of type string

Tags: node.js, firebase, lambda, google-cloud-firestore, netlify

I'm using `firebase-admin` to retrieve data and using `Netlify` Lambda functions to call the service. This is basically it.

Here is my code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const { id = "toronto" } = event.queryStringParameters;
  const cityRefs = dbInstance.collection("cities");
  console.log("req.params.id", id);

  if (id === "mumbai") {
    console.log("in here", id);
    let cityRef = cityRefs.doc("id1");
    return cityRef
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log("No such document!");
        } else {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
          callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: doc.data()
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting document", err);
        callback(err);
      });
    }
```

}

I keep getting the below error. I'm not exactly sure I'm doing wrong.

> Function invocation failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number

Comment: What line in the code you shared raises that error?

Comment: I do see the console log `in here` but then right after that the error occurs

Comment: You might try wrapping `doc.data()` in `JSON.stringify()`. You may also get more responses (and lots of friendly folks) on the Netlify Community! https://community.netlify.com/c/netlify-platform/functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason why it didn't work is because of `firebase-admin` was being bundled. So I used `https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals` to bundle `firebase-admin`. I added this to `webpack.functions.js`:

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
};
```

and I run the `netlify` `lambda` function with the following command:

```
"start:lambda": "netlify-lambda serve src/functions --config ./webpack.functions.js"
```

Comment: when using external got this error 

"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"